# Limit download over certain filesize through network

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

This is more of a network question rather than programming but Is there a way to limit a download over lets say 20MB to throttle at 16KB? I am trying to limit files over 20MB to throtle at lets say 16KB a second knowing its 20MB. Basically i would have a server between the Modem and my computer to do this. Is there any such way or solution/software to do this?

Basically if i start a download of a file thats over 20MB it will limit the entire download to 16KB.

Comment: at what level should this kick in? the browser? the os? your software firewall? how to detect what is a download? what about tunnels?

Comment: Basically a server thats between the computer and the Modem, something that will manage it on the servers end to the client. Should be anything downloaded on browser through http.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the client side (i.e. at home rather than in an ISP or on the server side) there are a number of products such as:

- http://www.netlimiter.com

If you want to do it on the server side, then the following answer gives an example for the very common Appache server:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13355834/334402

I am assuming you are not looking at this from an ISP point of view as they typically already know how to do this...

**UPDATED...**

ISP's will generally have dedicated solutions to police bandwidth and it will depend on the type of network.

For example a mobile operator will generally have very tight policy and rating controls in place, not only to avoid overuse (from their point of view) but also as some of the charging plans require tight controls to identify when a user goes out of bundle or when a pre-pay user needs to top up. The interfaces between the 'network' elements which transfer the data and the policy elements are (reasonably...) well defined in the standards and the solutions are often supplied by specialist rating and policy control solution vendors.

Fixed broadband providers will normally also have dedicated detection and control solutions, sometimes based on limits which are enforced at the customers modem, with central control.

If you are planning to build a solution for an ISP then you will need to give as much thought to scalability and availability as to the functionality itself. In particular if the system if being used for real time rating it will be critical that it does not fall over or slow down as that will have an immediate effect on your 'good' users as well as the ones you are trying to limit.

Comment: I am looking from an ISP pov actually. Im not talking about anything apache related or such.

Comment: Ahh - updated the answer with some notes on this. Good luck if you are building an ISP solution - that is a meaty project!!

Comment: Yeah the issue is these clients are going to get internet speeds that are probably 128kbit and 256kbit packages. And we limit them on certain downloads over a certain size, but thats the question i have no idea of any software or solution to capture these http downloads and limit them.

Comment: If you search through traffic shaping solutions and techniques I think you will probably find something that matches your requirement, or else get a feel for the usual industry approaches and possibly refine your approach. Most of the big router vendors will have some sort of traffic shaping solution, and there are dedicated solutions such as http://www.netequalizer.com which may address your needs.

Comment: I am going to write my own solution for this. I decided to have a custom solution built for me.